# Android - отправка POST запроса на сервер

Tags: android, java, post

Здравствуйте! Мне надо передать строку

```
    String DATA = "xajax=process&xajaxr=" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "&xajaxargs[]=" + 
                "<xjxquery><q>" + "countrycode=RU&to=" + dN + 
                "&m=" + dText + "&gLen=" + dText.length() + 
                "&from=&imgcode=" + dCaptcha.toUpperCase() + "&" + 
                hidName + "=" + hidValue + "</q></xjxquery>";
```

на сайт `http://www.mysite.com/send/`.
Подскажите, как правильно сформировать и отправить POST запрос (HTTP 1.1), не используя `NameValuePair`? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Открывай сокет и пиши в него строки, которые соответствуют протоколу HTTP. Мне пришлось так когда-то делать для заливки фото в ВК.

Comment: [Рекомендую :)][1]


  [1]: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Answer (score 5):

Вероятно вам нужно использовать эффективную библиотеку от Square для работы с http запросами. Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes) на доку.

Comment: AdamLuisSean, т.е. предложенная вами библиотека работает быстрее чем HttpURLConnection?
Спасибо за инфу!

Comment: SuperCreeper, да

Answer (score 1):

Я использую след. код:   (если есть кириллица или пробелы в отправляемых данных то делаю URLEncoder.encode("", "UTF-8"); )

```
         String postData = "" +
                "uid=" + SmallKey +
                "&chatId=" + _ChatId +
                "&image=" + _Base64IMG +
                "&startIndex=" + _LastIndex +
                "";
        URL url = new URL(_globalClasses.SendIMGMessURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postData.length()));
        // Write data
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(postData.getBytes());
        // Read response
        StringBuilder responseSB = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```